# Use Ruby on Rails in Javascript script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, widget, sonarqube

I try to create my own SonarQube Widget and I have the following question ?
I want to save in a javascript variable the result of my Metrics. The problem is that I don't succeed to use Ruby on Rails with Javascript.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">        
     var text =  "<%= format_measure('sonar.metric.arcadsoftware.rpg.ruleset1') %>";
     alert(text);
</script>
```

If I use just `<p><%= format_measure('sonar.metric.arcadsoftware.rpg.ruleset1') -%> </p>` the result is "True" on my widget.
So I want to store the String 'True' in my javascript variable **text**.

Thank you

Comment: Your code works on my views when I replace format_measure('sonar.metric.arcadsoftware.rpg.ruleset1') by 'True'. Where do you put your <script> ?

Comment: I find a solution to stock in a js variable, the value of the Metric.          **var measure_value = '<%= measure(Metric key').text_value -%>';**